# mostrar color del texto según valor almacenado

Tags: php, pdo

saludos amigos tengo un problema con un código mi problema es que no se me alinea como debería ser y aparte no me convence tengo otra manea de hacerlo, pero no directamente desde la base de datos si no manual.

código 1.

```
<h6 class="black-text left-align"><b>Estado:</b>&nbsp;
 <?php $svg = '<svg height="10" width="400"><text x="60" y="1" style="fill:%s;">'.$linea['estados'].'</svg>'; 
  printf($svg, $linea['color']);?>
```

de esta forma se me muestra lo requerido pero no se me alinea junto al texto.

código 2

```
$status_color = array(
                    'Fuera de Servicio' => 'col s8 card-panel red darken-2 center',
                    'Activo' => 'col s8 card-panel yellow darken-2 center'
                          );



echo "<h6 class="black-text left-align"><b>Estado:</b>&nbsp;

           <div class='". $status_color[$linea['color']] ."'>
            <p class='black-text'>$linea[estados]</p></div></td>";
```

en el código 2 no se como debería hacer para llamar los valores desde la base de datos y mostrar el texto en color de acuerdo a su valor registrado en la bd.

anexo la imagen como se muestra
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

listo ya pude solucionarlo anexo la solución de esta manera trabaja con los datos almacenados en la base de datos

```
echo "<span class='black-text'><b>Estado:</b>&nbsp;</span><span style='color:".$linea['color_estados']."'><b>".$linea['estados']."</b></span>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Según lo que te entiendo quieres darle estilo a tu "h6"

Quedaría algo así directamente al elemento:

```
<h6 style='text-align: center'><b>Estado</b></h6>
```

De forma externa en archivo .php/html

```
<h6 class='nombreClase'><b>Estado</b></h6>
```

archivo .css

```
.nombreClase{
text-aling: center;
}
```

Comment: gracias por responder amigo pero lo que quiero es llamar desde la base de datos el color de cada estado y mostrarlo en el texto ejemplo: estado: activo: verde, estado inactivo: rojo ahora lo que quiero lograr es que si el texto a mostrar es activo debe mostrarse de color verde, y si es fuera de servicio debe mostrarse de color rojo